# What does BTRS31753 mean in a user agent (IE8)

Tags: windows, internet-explorer-8, user-agent

In order to reproduce an obscure bug one of our user is experiencing (well at least one), I'm trying to figure out what

```
BTRS31753
```

stands for in a user agent. Here's the full UA string :

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; BTRS31753; GTB7.4; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; FREE; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152
```

I've manage to install the Google Toolbar and all the .NET framework versions, but I still can't reproduce the bug or figure out what "BTRS31753" stands for...

If that helps, the user is on IE8/WinXp and he can't use radios and checkboxes.

For fully supported browsers (IE9+, FF, Chrome, Safari) the radios and checkboxes have a custom design, with a fallback to normal inputs in IE8 and less as the selector fails. It could be that the fallback isn't being applied because the conditional body classes isn't added, because of some pluggin or whatever.

I hope someone knows or can figure out where this little bit comes from so I can test and either reproduce the bug or move on to better and bigger things (like IE10 bugs -_-")

Thanks :)

Comment: Quacks like an app created by "Treasury Software Corp", a company that's in the business of online payments.  http://whois.domaintools.com/btrs-file-creator.com

Comment: Any idea how I could install whatever their software is so I could reproduce the bug myself ? I don't even know why that use would have anything from them install, it doesn't make any sense...